# Разделить блоки на две колонки

Tags: javascript, css

У меня есть один контенер, в котором N-количество блоков. Я хочу разделить их на две колонки. Хотелось бы обернуть одну половину в div и другую половину в div и потом flex. 
Код сгенерирован плагином и я не могу поставить это сам. Надо очень очень срочно. Помогите пожалуйста

```
<div class="container">

  <div> < /div>
  <div> < /div>
  <div> < /div>
  <div> < /div>
  <div> < /div>
  <div> < /div>
  <div> < /div>
  <div> < /div>
  <div> < /div>
  <div> < /div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можете задать flex контейнеру, а блокам - width: 50%, и они сами выстроятся в две колонки:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container > div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>

</div>
```